# Array type has incomplete element type , could not pass struct array to the function

Tags: c, arrays, file, structure

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("how many students:\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
   struct std
    {
        int rollNo;
        char FirstName[15];
        char SecondName[15];
        char fatherName[20];
        char motherName[20];
        char institute [50];
        char deptt[20];
        int sem;
        float cgpa;
        float sgpa;
        float height;
        float weight;
        char citizenship[10];
        char lang1[15];
        char lang2[15];
        int no_siblings;
        char sub1[15];
        char sub2[15];
        char sub3[15];
        float marks_12;

    }Array[n],*s;
    writes(&s,n,Array);
    return 0;
}

void writes(struct std *s,int n,struct std Array[n])
{   int i;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("serially enter \n roll-no,\n first name,\n second name,\n father's name,\n mother's name,\n institute name,\n department,\n semester,\n cgpa,\n sgpa,\n height,\n weight,\n citizenship,\n lang1,\n lang2,\n no of siblings,\n sub1,\n sub2,\n sub3,\n class 12 board's %age marks scored\n");
        scanf("%d",Array[i].rollNo);
        gets(Array[i].FirstName);
        gets(Array[i].SecondName);
        gets(Array[i].fatherName);
        gets(Array[i].motherName);
        gets(Array[i].institute);
        gets(Array[i].deptt);
    }

}
```

i am starting to write a code where i can pass an array of the structure std to a function to take inputs but I am getting an error saying "Array type has incomplete element type",

i am beginner, i tried a lot but could not solve it. Please help.

Comment: You need to declare (and definne) `struct std` outside the scope of `main`, so that `writes` can also see the definition.

Comment: Also `void writes(struct std *s,` --> `void writes(struct std **s,`

Comment: the posted code does not compile.  When compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings. (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=gnu11 -Wconversion`)

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line.  3) separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent)

Comment: function names and parameter names should indicate `content` or `usage` (or better, both).

Comment: the posted code contains several 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  10, 15, 20, 50.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc. Suggest using a `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: the function: `gets()` had been depreciated for years and completely eliminated in the latest C standard.  Suggest using statements similar to: ` fgets( Array[i].FirstName, sizeof( Array[i].FirstName, stdin );`

Comment: @user3629249 the question is about why the code does not compile, so saying "the posted code does not compile" is not very useful.  The main error message appears in the question (although it would have been better to post the exact message)

Comment: @M.M,  There was such a long list of 'whys' the posted code does not compile, that I decided, in my answer, to indicate the correct way to do things rather than enumerate each compiler message and why that message was being output.

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code

1. cleanly compiles
2. uses presently available functions, rather than deleted functions
3. respects the width of the terminal
4. properly uses a format parameter in the call to `printf()`
5. properly checks for error indications from system functions (fgets(), scanf() )
6. properly defines the struct so the definition is visible throughout the code
7. eliminates 'magic' numbers
8. uses appropriate horizontal and vertical spacing
9. clears the array before setting values
10. demonstrates how long strings can be broken into short strings
11. removes unused parameters from call to `writes()`
12. properly provides a prototype for the `writes()` function
13. keeps data local to where it is used

And now, the proposed code example

```
#include <stdio.h>   // printf(), scanf(), perror()
#include <stdlib.h>  // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE
#include <string.h>  // memset()

#define LEN_FIRSTNAME   15
#define LEN_SECONDNAME  15
#define LEN_FATHERNAME  20
#define LEN_MOTHERNAME  20
#define LEN_INSTITUTE   50
#define LEN_DEPTT       20
#define LEN_CITIZENSHIP 10
#define LEN_LANG1       15
#define LEN_LANG2       15
#define LEN_SUB1        15
#define LEN_SUB2        15
#define LEN_SUB3        15

struct std
{
    int rollNo;
    char FirstName[ LEN_FIRSTNAME ];
    char SecondName[ LEN_SECONDNAME ];
    char fatherName[ LEN_FATHERNAME ];
    char motherName[ LEN_MOTHERNAME ];
    char institute [ LEN_INSTITUTE ];
    char deptt[ LEN_DEPTT ];
    int sem;
    float cgpa;
    float sgpa;
    float height;
    float weight;
    char citizenship[ LEN_CITIZENSHIP ];
    char lang1[ LEN_LANG1 ];
    char lang2[ LEN_LANG2 ];
    int no_siblings;
    char sub1[ LEN_SUB1 ];
    char sub2[ LEN_SUB2 ];
    char sub3[ LEN_SUB3 ];
    float marks_12;
};


// prototypes
void writes( int n, struct std Array[n] );


int main( void )
{

    int n;
    printf("how many students:\n");
    if( 1 != scanf("%d",&n) )
    {
        perror( "scanf for number of students failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }


    // implied else, scanf successful

    struct std Array[n];
    memset( Array, '\0', sizeof(Array) );

    writes( n, Array );
    return 0;
}


void writes( int n, struct std Array[n] )
{
    for( int i=0; i<n; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%s",
                "serially enter \n"
                "roll-no,\n"
                "first name,\n"
                "second name,\n"
                "father's name,\n"
                "mother's name,\n"
                "institute name,\n"
                "department,\n" );
                // semester,\n cgpa,\n sgpa,\n height,\n weight,\n citizenship,\n lang1,\n lang2,\n no of siblings,\n sub1,\n sub2,\n sub3,\n class 12 board's %age marks scored\n");

        if( 1 != scanf("%d", &(Array[i].rollNo)) )
        {
            perror( "scanf for roll-no failed" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, scanf for roll-no successful

        if( !fgets( Array[i].FirstName, sizeof( Array[i].FirstName), stdin ) )
        {
            perror( "fgets for FirstName failed" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, fgets for FirstName successful

        // remove possible trailing newline
        char *newline = NULL;
        if( (newline = strchr( Array[i].FirstName, '\n' ) ) )
        {
            *newline = '\0';
        }

        //---etc---
    }
}
```

Comment: IMO all the `LEN` defines are clutter (and should be enums rather than defines), it'd be better to use the number in the array definition and then use `sizeof` to access the sizes as needed

Comment: @M.M,  I agree that it would be cleaner to use a `enum`, however I always have to keep in mind that beginning programmers do not (usually) have a complete grasp of the C language and therefore I try to keep things as simple as possible.